# Any way to edit redshift tables in Excel?

Tags: excel, amazon-redshift, devart

I've been looking for a way to be able to edit AWS Redshift tables in Excel.
I know with ODBC I can connect to a table and work with a readonly version. But does anybody know of a solution to write back?

I found 2 addins that write back to Postgres (http://www.savetodb.com/ and https://www.devart.com/excel-addins/) but I couldn't get them to work with Redshift.

A limited hack I currently use is to have a column next to my external data range which generates sql commands (e.g. updates, inserts) and I then manually paste them into my SQL client.

However what I would like to do is be able to edit my redshift table in-line in Excel.

Anybody know of a solution?

Comment: Do post an answer if you find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found 2 addins that write back to Postgres (http://www.savetodb.com/ and https://www.devart.com/excel-addins/) but I couldn't get them to work with Redshift.

Please describe what exactly you tried to do and what exactly didn't work for you in Devart Excel Add-in for PostgreSQL.

We have tested Devart Excel Add-in for PostgreSQL with Redshift database. We can successfully get data from a database into an Excel worksheet, modify data, and send the modified data to the server.

You can connect to a database and import data from the database to an Excel sheet. After this you may work with these data like with a usual Excel table. After this, you can save changed data back to the database. You can find more detailed information in our documentation. You can find the link to the documentation in the Start Menu 'Start Menu->All Programs->Devart Excel Add-ins->Documentation' if you installed Excel Add-in for PostgreSQL with the 'Help files' check box selected. Excel Add-ins can be downloaded from [our site](https://www.devart.com/excel-addins/download.html).

You can edit existing rows of a table and add new ones and submit changes back to the data source. For this, perform the following actions:

1. After you have imported data, on the Ribbon click "Edit Mode";
2. Make the necessary data changes, and click Commit. The changes will be sent to the server;
3. Click "Edit Mode" again to turn off the edit mode.

Comment: Yes, i can confirm that I now got it work. Great stuff!